# Cross-platform WebRTC development kit

Tags: web-development, cross-platform, framework, mobile, real-time

What whould be a good cross-platform development kit for WebRTC?

By good I mean:

- it provides interoperable libraries for developing for Web, iOS and Android
- supports audio/video chat in rooms
- preferably free/open source
- one time payment for SDK is OK, recurrent payment per minute/traffic/storage is not; budget would be in the order of thousands
- support/fallback for IE & Safari on web (but this is not mandatory)

I already had a look at JavaScript frameworks like EasyRTC, PeerJS or SimpleWebRTC. These are nice for web but I'm quite worried that coming later with a mobile app able to interop with the same infrastructure (e.g. join from mobile a room created on web) would be difficult.

Thanks!